# basic question about inequalities and supremum and infimum

Tags: calculus

Let $f: A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ and suppose for any $x,y \in A , |f(x) - f(y)| \leq M $

Can we conclude that

$$ \sup_{x \in A} f(x) - \inf_{x \in A} f(x) \leq  M $$

Comment: Is the given $M$ supposed to the same as the one below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** consider a sequence $(x_n, y_n)$
such as
$(f(x_n), f(y_n))\to (\inf_A f, \sup_A f)$

---

details:
 for every $n$ there is $x_n$ such as 
$\inf_A f \le f(x_n) < \inf_A f + \frac 1n$, and then $f(x_n)\to \inf_A f$.

Make the same construction for $y_n$.

Then take the limit in the inequality
$$
f(y_n) - f(x_n) \le M
$$

you get
$$ 
\sup_A f - \inf_A f \le M.
$$